# Cannot run maven tasks in Intellij - maven home not valid

Tags: windows, maven, intellij-idea

I'm running IntelliJ on windows, and am trying to run a task on a maven plugin. Whenever I do so ('Run Maven Build' from the right-click menu), I get an error saying

> No valid Maven installation found. Either set the home directory, or set the M2_HOME env variable.

I already have maven dependencies downloaded into `%userprofile%\.m2`. If I set the home directory to `%userprofile%\.m2`, I get another error:

> <dir> is not a valid Maven home directory.

What is a valid Maven home directory, and how do I get one on windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify the maven directory where all the executables are. Go to Project -> Settings -> Maven "Maven home directory". For me this is F:\programme\apache-maven-3.0.5. Maven will then download all dep. to the m2 directory.

Comment: Are the exes distributed with IntelliJ somewhere, or do I have to download them?